# How to print first 10 lines instead of the whole list using pprint

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is printing 10 lines only instead of the whole list using `pprint(dict(str_types))`

Here is my code

```
from collections import defaultdict

str_type_re = re.compile(r'\b\S+\.?$', re.IGNORECASE)

expected = ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard", "Drive", "Court", "Place", "Square", "Lane", "Road", 
            "Trail", "Parkway", "Commons"]

def audit_str_type(str_types, str_name, rex):
    stn = rex.search(str_name)
    if stn :
        str_type = stn.group()
        if str_type not in expected:
            str_types[str_type].add(str_name)
```

I defined a function that audits tag elements where k="addr:street", and also any tag elements match the is_str_name function.

```
def audit(osmfile,rex):
    osm_file = open(osmfile, "r", encoding="utf8")
    str_types = defaultdict(set)
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(osm_file, events=("start",)):

        if elem.tag == "node" or elem.tag == "way":
            for tag in elem.iter("tag"):
                if is_str_name(tag):
                    audit_str_type(str_types, tag.attrib['v'],rex)

    return str_types
```

In the code above , I used "is_str_name" function to filter tag when calling the audit function to audit street names.

```
def is_str_name(elem):
    return (elem.attrib['k'] == "addr:street")

str_types = audit(mydata, rex = str_type_re)
pprint.pprint(dict(str_types[:10]))
```

Comment: After adding `import re` I got `NameError: name 'mydata' is not defined` please provide a [Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  or at least the output you are getting and expected output.

Comment: `pprint.pprint(dict(str_types[:10]))` What's wrong with that, it certainly looks like it only prints 10. This really needs a [mcve].

Comment: @MorganThrapp `str_types` is a `defaultdict`, it doesn't support slicing. (but yes this is missing a MCVE)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Oh, you're right. Incidentally, this is why an mcve would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) to get back the string representation of the object instead of printing it directly, then you can split it up by lines and only print out the first few:

```
whole_repr = pprint.pformat(dict(str_types))

for line in whole_repr.splitlines()[:10]:
    print(line)
```

Note that I couldn't test this since you did not have a MCVE but I did verify it with a more trivial example:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> thing = pprint.pformat({i:str(i) for i in range(10000)})
>>> type(thing), len(thing)
(<class 'str'>, 147779)
>>> for line in thing.splitlines()[:10]:print(line)

{0: '0',
 1: '1',
 2: '2',
 3: '3',
 4: '4',
 5: '5',
 6: '6',
 7: '7',
 8: '8',
 9: '9',
```